# QSerialPort Missing Bytes

Tags: c++, qt

I am using QSerialPort to do sending and receiving on different program.

In my sender program, I packed a unsigned char and one unsigned short to be sent over to the receiver program.

This is my sender:

```
unsigned char char1 = 200;
unsigned short ushort1 = 65534;

QByteArray data;
QDataStream dataStream(&data, QIODevice::WriteOnly);

dataStream << char1;
dataStream << uShort1;

serialPort->write(data);
```

This my receiver:

```
QObject::connect(serialPort, &QSerialPort::readyRead, [&]()
{
     QByteArray data = serialPort->readAll();
}
```

all baud rate, parity, data, stop and flow control are set identical for sender and receiver.
However, on the receiver side, i only receive the first byte.

Please advise.

Comment: `readAll` can in general not know when the serialport is done sending. All you know from the `readyRead` signal is that there is *at least one byte* ready to read. You need to collect and assemble the read fragments into a buffer of your own if you want to make sense of individual transmissins.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait until your serial port receives whole parcel

```
QByteArray data = serialPort->readAll();
while (m_serialPort->waitForReadyRead(10)) {
    data += m_serialPort->readAll();
}
```

You may play with delay value with is in msecs depends on your hardware

A good practice is to wait for bytes has been written on sender's side as well

```
...
serialPort->write(data);
if (!serialPort->waitForBytesWritten(100)) {
    qDebug() << "Error sending data";
}
```